# GWT Text Area Style

Tags: java, gwt, textarea, smartgwt

For some reason, I can't seem to change the font or font size in my GWT TextAreas. The default font for text areas doesn't even match with the rest of the default fonts, it looks like notepad font for some reason. I've tried adding and setting style names, but the font will not change, only the color and other parts of the TextArea will change. I think I may have broken something earlier when I added, then removed SmartGWT. Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your theme inherit line in your Module.gwt.xml file to verify you have one gwt theme included (normally when using smartgwt we put in comment this one ) and no smartclient theme inherited.
Have a look on your TextAreas with firebug to see which css class is applied and check in your css file to see if you have any entry for this class.

Comment: Alrighty, I took your advice. The theme inherit was fine, so I used firebug, and found this:

    `.ace_editor > textarea {`
    `.ace_editor > textarea.ace_composition {`

Where everywhere else there is a "." instead of a ">". Do you know what this means?

Comment: To me it's meaning you are using Ace Code editor somewhere, probably due to some Firebug option (if you don't include it in your own project). These css class are not the gwt ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and so used the Chrome inspector to find out why my styles were not being applied. It seems that they were being ignored because of settings in clean.css. So then I did:

```css
.gwt-TextArea {
 font-family : monospace !important;
 font-size : 10pt !important;
}
```

And that worked.